# Jquery Datatable Error in Responsive

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I want to put a background color in TD on my Datatable table.
It works well, but in responsive, the color goes away!
you can see more clearly here: http://jsfiddle.net/4x69duk5/3/

HTML:

```
<td class="color-table"><div style="background-color:red"></div></td>
```

CSS:

```
td.color-table div{
    width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 1px solid #676a6c;
}
```

Resize JSFiddle windows, you will see colors dissapears in responsive...

Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: That is the default behavior for DataTables. Check https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-control/auto.html

Comment: Hmmm... So that's no way to fix it? =(

Comment: Yes, there is. Check https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/columnPriority.html

Comment: i set ` data-priority="1" ` in my TH on Thead and it works well. Thanks a lot ! =)